# segregate data and assign new value R

Tags: r

I have a column for Time which has data range between 0000 - 2399
I have 2.5 million rows and each cell has different values for time.

I wish to segregate my data into 4

```
Night 0000:0700
Morning 0701:1200
Afternoon 1201:1800
Evening 1801:2359
```

So if the time range is between 0000:0700 assign the value of 1 for all values within the new column.

```
mydata$NEWTIME <- as.nemeric(factor(mydata$TIME,
   level=range(0000:0700,0701:1200,1201:1800,1801:2359))
```

this is not working and I am sure I am doing something silly. Could you please help me?

Comment: You should use the function `cut()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
mydata$TIME[mydata$TIME>0000 & mydata$TIME<0700]<-"Night"
mydata$TIME[mydata$TIME>0701 & mydata$TIME<1200]<-"Morning"
mydata$TIME[mydata$TIME>1201 & mydata$TIME<1800]<-"Afternoon"
mydata$TIME[mydata$TIME>1801 & mydata$TIME<2359]<-"Evening"
```

Comment: hey @User7598 do you want me to write this within my code? or as a separate line

Comment: write it as a separate line

Comment: I just tried this it returns object 'TIME' not found

Comment: Is it possible for you to write the whole line please? my file is read as mydata

Comment: I had to add mydata$TIME infront, its working now. Thanks @User7598 (Y)